# Logistic/Ordinal regression with clustered robust standard errors in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression

How to run logistic and/or ordinal logistic regression with  **robust clustered standard errors**?

I thought `Zelig` will do it – but the `robust` and `cluster` function is no longer available!

Example (it was very easy)

```
ordinal <- zelig(Y ~ X1+X2, model = "ologit", robust=TRUE, **cluster**="id", data = df))
```

There are of course other ways of doing it. For example using `robcov` function in `rms` package. But this is too time-consuming if you are running 500 different models (like I do now..) So are there any other ways of getting robust clustered standard errors similar to what `Zelig` had before?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: how familiar are you with `github`? My advice would be to go to [repo](https://github.com/izahn/Zelig) and look into past commits when the function still had this parameter. This way you could just download the old `zeilig` package onto your local machine and run the analysis. One must be careful though, there might be a reason for them removing this parameter from that specific function

Comment: @HanjoJo'burgOdendaal Thanks. I'm afraid I have some very basic knowledge of github. it seems strange though if there are no other packages that can do it – don't you agree?

Comment: I need help with this too!!!!!!

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian Please let me know if you find a solution to this. thanks